# postman: namespace on the "MasterDataReplReqMsg" element, is not a valid SOAP version

Tags: web-services, soap, postman

I am using postman to post a SOAP message to a target URL https://testacig.ariba.com/cxf/receiveERPMD. below is the payload

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<n0:MasterDataReplReqMsg xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:proxy:DD2:/1SAI/TASD374B56E2305E7E70622:754" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:n0="http://sap.com/xi/ARBCIG1">
    <Header>
        <Parameters>
            <Parameter name="UUID">
                <value>005056893BDD1EDB88E738052AFE58D8</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter name="realm">
                <value>relamname</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter name="fullload">
                <value>true</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter name="event">
                <value>Import External System Master Data</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter name="clienttype">
                <value>DirectConnect</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter name="clientversion">
                <value>Addon- Direct Connectivity</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter name="clientinfo">
                <value>10.242.99.33-nbaps492</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter name="operation">
                <Parameter name="systemId">
                    <value>DECLNT111</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter name="Solution">
                    <Parameter name="SystemId">
                        <value>DECLNT111</value>
                    </Parameter>
                </Parameters>
                <AttachmentFolder fileName="processing20201110104659_1.zip" contentType="application/zip" contentLength="" contentID="FOL33000000000004EXT39000000000138">
                    <Content xmlns="">UEsDBBQAAAAIAN5ValFIb/vgcAAAAIgAAAAOAAAASXRlbU1hc3Rlci5jc3YLDXHTteDyTSxJLcpMzPErzU1KLdKBcUMqC1LhHPei/NICHafE4tTQvMyS/DTf1MTi0qJUHf+ilNQikJBOcmlxSX6uW2ZqTgqXkrOHroGhroGRko6Sm2tQCJDyMTAwBlIBzq5AEoggysMSc0pTlbgAUEsDBBQAAAAIAN5ValHkI36wfAAAAJEAAAAdAAAASXRlbU1hc3RlckRlc2NyaXB0aW9uTGFuZy5jc3ZVjTsOwjAQBXufwnJtSwkVNUkgBaTh06/xyrK0WUfrWFwfU9I9aWb0no+zO6ob7CgJaKmrR7EjlrekbU+Z7RU4VoiozDC7rnfdwVhzAY9UdtgIRZ</Content>
                </AttachmentFolder>
            </Header>
        </n0:MasterDataReplReqMsg>
```

when do POST request I get below error message and status code as 500

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode>
            <faultstring>"http://sap.com/xi/ARBCIG1", the namespace on the "MasterDataReplReqMsg" element, is not a valid SOAP version.</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

what could be the reason ?

Comment: Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap your payload in a SOAP envelope. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <n0:MasterDataReplReqMsg ...>
  ...
  </n0:MasterDataReplReqMsg>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```